# Passing table index to my vuex store

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to pass the record to be deleted and the index of the table so it can be updated.

It seems the delete works fine but removing the right record from the table is not.

I ve tried a few variations and read a lot but still can't quite figure this out so seeking guidance please.

My component

```
//recordID - record to delete from API
// index - index in table
// console log returns correct info for both
onDelete (recordId, index) {
  this.$store.dispatch('cases/deleteCase', recordId, index)
}

// also tried this.$store.dispatch('cases/deleteCase', (recordId, index)) but didn't work or delete
```

In my store I have

Action

```
deleteCase ({ commit, context }, data, index) {
  console.log(data)
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
   //Delete works as expected
   this.$axios.delete('/cases/' + data + '.json')
  .then(
   resolve(commit('DELETE_CASE', index))
    )
    .catch(e => {
      context.error(e)
      reject('/cases/')
    })
  })
},
```

My mutation

```
// delete a todo
DELETE_CASE (state, index) {
  state.cases.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, sharing for others with similar issue

need to pass an object

```
onDelete (recordId, index) {
this.payload = {'recordId': recordId, 'index': index}
 this.$store.dispatch('cases/deleteCase', this.payload)
}
```

Then I can separate out in my vuex action

```
deleteCase ({ commit, context }, payload) {
      return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
       this.$axios.delete('/cases/' + payload.recordId + '.json')
      .then(
       resolve(commit('DELETE_CASE', payload.index))
        )
        .catch(e => {
          context.error(e)
          reject('/cases/')
        })
      })
    },
```